# Are hosted bare-metal servers more secure than VPS against unauthorized disclosure?

Tags: confidentiality, threat-modeling, vps

Our small company needs to store sensitive data in the cloud. We are debating VPS's or rented bare-metal servers due to cost. Our threat model includes malicious sysadmins working at the hosting provider and this is what we are focusing on, not side-channel attacks from other customers on the VPS etc. Our policies require FDE using LUKS and we have tested unlocking the disks with both Linode and bare-metal servers using dropbear.

We know that neither solution is secure against a determined and well-resourced attacker. We know that FDE was not designed as a logical control to protect against unauthorized disclosure on a running system. However we need to assess the degree of increased risk when using a VPS.

Pro-bare-metal team argue malicious sysadmins can more easily access VM from host OS and therefor bare-metal protects against less capable sysadmins. This could enable them dump memory and access sensitive data. Or for example replace dropbear with malicious version on unencrypted boot partition.

The pro-VPS team argue that all of the above is equally possible with a dedicated server and since sysadmin has access to hardware its game over anyway.  They agree it would likely require malicious actor to have more skill/time with higher chance of being detected. e.g. they may have to reboot server to implant payload.

Both teams agree that probability of attack from capable malicious sysadmin is low and therefor the risk of unauthorized disclosure for the VPS is medium and dedicated is low. Due to the massive cost savings the business are keen to accept the risk and go with VPS.

I feel this could be missing whole classes of attack vectors and so I'd like to ask the community what we could be missing?

Comment: I'm confused by, "`The pro-VPS team argue that all of the above is equally possible with a dedicated server and since sysadmin has access to hardware its game over anyway.`".  Presumably the sysadmin of *your* bare metal server in this case would be an employee of your company, not an employee of the data center where your bare metal server is hosted.  I'm not sure why a sysadmin at the data center would have access to your hardware (unless you specifically contract for this).  Some data centers even offer lockable cabinets, to ensure this.

Comment: Yes we would admin the server but its also under the control of a sysadmin at the data center who has access to the IPMI/BMC and can freely reboot the system and access the hardware so ultimately he can do anything. We don't have the funds to rent an entire lockable rack, we need only a few servers.

Comment: I see your dilemma.  You want to have an on-site admin that can access the server for rescuing, troubleshooting, etc.; but at the same time, you don't want that admin to have access to the serer for security reasons.  Hard to have it both ways.  FYI, DRAC cards are useful for remote access to the console for rescuing, troubleshooting, remote rebooting, etc.

Comment: With regard to pricing, it's been a while since I've looked into physical hosting in a data center, but if memory serves me correctly, I think the going rate for a quarter rack (which is 8U, enough to hold a few servers) is about $200/month (including power and a modest amount of bandwidth), and many providers offer lockable cabinets.  So, certainly within reach, even for a small startup, and with remote access cards as I described above (which give you access to the console even if the server is offline), possible to administer without data center employees having physical access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Our threat model includes malicious sysadmins working at the hosting provider and this is what we are focusing on ...*

If this is truly your primary threat concern, then Virtual vs Physical is a false dichotomy. Nothing short of physically hosting and protecting it yourself is going to address that threat.

FDE protects dead, as in non-running, systems not running systems. Servers in particular need the ability to **restart**. This means either manual intervention or stored keys at the server. This requires a trusted admin, which is counter to your primary concern.

You mentioned **cost** as the driver to a hosted system. If cost is overiding **trust**, your best bet is to use what you believe to be the most trusted provider. Many companies and organizations already do this, but you have to make the decision as to which is more important.

**You simply are not going to be able to have a secure untrusted provider.**,

Comment: Thank you, very insightful. I did state "we know FDE is not designed to protect against unauthorized disclosure on a running system". We cannot afford to host our own servers and we are a remote team and have no physical office. So we are trying to ascertain whether the risk of a compromise on bare-metal is lower than VM at the same hosting company, same level of trust. It would seem the main benefit is a small extra effort and potential alert of compromise (needing to reboot bare-metal) but if there really is no difference in risk then VPS is clearly better business decision.